React native DEbugger support for React Native 0.74.0
Hi due to latest experimental debuugger introduces in react native 0.74.0 we cant use React native debugger anymore and unable to debugg network and redux.
Annyone could help me setup React Native debugger with RN0.74.0?

use flipper https://fbflipper.com/

flipper was removed in 0.74. I can't find any instructions on how to integrate flipper with 0.74

To debbug redux in react native 0.74 you must follow these steps
1 - install reacttotron in your system (it's a cliente as flipper)
https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/releases/tag/reactotron-app%403.7.0
2 - install reactotron-react-native and reactotron-redux (as dev dependencies) in your project
3 - add in your store folder ( or where you prefer)
ReactotronConfig file
config example:
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";
import { reactotronRedux } from "reactotron-redux";

const reactotron = Reactotron.configure({ name: "BookList" })
  .use(reactotronRedux())
  .connect(); // let's connect!

export default reactotron;

4 - configure your store (in my case redux/tooklit)
example:
import { configureStore, Store } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IBookState, BookSlice } from "../bookSlice/BookSlice";
import { IUserState, UserSlice} from '../userSlice/UserSlice';
import reactotron from "./ReactotronConfig";

export interface IApplicationState {
  readonly bookState: IBookState;
  readonly userState: IUserState;
}

export const store: Store<IApplicationState> = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    bookState: BookSlice.reducer,
    userState: UserSlice.reducer,
  },
  enhancers: (getDefaultEngancers) => 
    getDefaultEngancers({
    
  }).concat(reactotron.createEnhancer()),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

5 - open your reacttreactotron app and then refresh you react app => now you can see the redux state in timeline tab.
